# How to get the index of each element using jQuery each function

Tags: jquery, events, each

I'm making an menu and for that I use jquery to display data.

I want to make it more dynamic and for that I'm using the `each()` function

Here is an representative example of my code http://jsfiddle.net/4r5cLy00/

As you can see the on click displays all the listitems of the unordered list and that's not want i want. I want to get the clicked `<li>`

I hope someone have a simple solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean like this?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('ul > li').click(function() {
        alert($(this).text());
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4r5cLy00/1/

Comment: exactly! Why do you use the operator instead of space?

Comment: sorry, which operator do you mean? Is it the `>` (greater than) symbol? That just means the `li`'s that are *direct* descendants of the the `ul`. It could be written as `$('ul li')` and still work fine but it would work for any child `li`'s aswell which you may or may not want. It's also useful in CSS if you only want to style top level `li`'s for example.

Comment: A space would just be a descendant selector. The ``>`` denotes a child selector. It's just a way to give more specificity.
https://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/

Comment: The only thing I don't like about this solution is that it doesn't use event delegation. You can do this with one event bound the the ``<ul>`` instead of x number of list items.

Comment: Thanks @jeff and for your replies and explanation!

Answer (score 0):

This is how you'd use **event delegation** in this instance. It's a good practice and every JS programmer should use it. The advantages are that you only bind one event and you get better performance. Read more here:

http://bdadam.com/blog/plain-javascript-event-delegation.html

```js
$('ul').click(function(event) {
  if (event.target.tagName == 'LI') {
    console.log(event.target.innerText);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
  <li>item 3</li>
</ul>
```